# Setting android view location has no effect

Tags: android, android-studio, android-widget, android-view

I have a simple view inside of a RelativeLayout that I animate up & down so it slides off and on screen. This works every time except the very first time, where the animation does nothing.

This lead me to trying to set the Y location manually in the activity's onCreate() method. Oddly, that had no effect either.

Is there some reason a view's Y location can't be set until after the activity has been fully displayed? If not, why am I seeing this weird behavior, and is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The first time you're calling it's before the view has laid out.

You can get around this by listening for the view to be laid out.

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                
                // Perform whatever actions you want here
            }
        });
```

Comment: Cool, I'll give that a try. Does the layout change dynamically as I animate the one view up and down, or does it just snap to the new layout then animates the other view out?